# MVC - Submit form to controller or model

Tags: php

I'm trying to apply a simple MVC pattern to my current website without any frameworks. Since i havent really gotten into oop yet im still using procedural at the moment.

i have a simple login form (view)

```
<form action="controller/login.php" method="Post">
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
<input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
<input type="submit" value="Sign in" />
</form>
```

this form will submit to the controller for login form. Controller will now check if both fields have inputs and "cleanse" more or less the input

```
if(isset($_POST['username'])){
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$username_escape = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $username);
$password_escape = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $password);
}

header("../model/login.php");
```

this is a really simple check right now however i was now wondering should i include controller into model and redirect to model from controller or form submit it at first place and have controller included.

Model

```
include_once("../controller/login.php");
$query = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT into DB_table (username, password)
VALUES($username_escape, $password_escape)");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's good that you're trying to separate your concerns, but MVC is a design pattern based on top of OOP principles.

OOP works with objects, and those objects are defined by a class, which is like a blueprint.

So in this example, you'd want everything to go through the controller, then depending on whether you want to save out, you'd want to call the model.

eg.

```
class LoginController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        if(!is_null($username) AND !is_null($password))
        {
             $user = new \Service\User();
             $credentialsAreValid = $user->checkCredentials($username, $password);
             if($credentialsAreValid)
             {
                 header("Redirect: Somewhere");
             }
        }

        require_once __DIR__."/../templates/login.php";
    }
}

class User
{
    public function checkCredentials($username, $password)
    {
         $dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db";
         $dbuser = "root";
         $dbpass = "pass";
         $db = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass);
       
         $sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
         $sth->bindValue(1, $username);
         $sth->bindValue(2, $password);

         $sth->execute();
         if(count($sth->fetchAll())>0) return true;
         return false;
    }
}
```

As you can see the logic is separated into a service, and is only called if it is needed. We've also used PDO to prevent SQL injections, (though one shouldn't really be creating objects in here).

I would suggest you look into autoloading, and have a play with a framework like Silex as it will teach you these principles.

Comment: This is clear explanation, never stroke me that i should do vice versa and call model if arguments is valid in the controller file. I'm really new to MVC and oop thinking becouse its so diffirent from procedural PHP programming. Yeah params stroke me aswell i will adept to it when i start using more oop.

Answer (score 3):

1. AS FOR MODELS, create a model class for every db table. In each class, declare methods for specific actions, for example saveRegistrationForm($form) in User model (for user table). Do not call controllers inside models!
2. IN CONTROLLER, include MODELS, so you can call their methods. In controller, you would read the post into some variables (as you did), then validate them somehow, and then save data to db, using specific model method.

Judging by your question, I reckon your MVC and OOP knowledge are little. If you want to dive into these topics (great idea!), I would reccomend playing with various MVC frameworks first and learning how they work, before you try to create your own framework. :)

Comment: never stroke me that i should do vice versa. I'm very new to the thoughts of MVC and OOP since it´s strange compared to traditional procedural programming, javascript encourage to path over from procedural to oop.