# Am I using the MVC structure in an incorrect manner?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, view, model, postdata

I recently followed a tutorial on how to set up an `MVC` structure in `PHP`. This tutorial is located [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLfdtiltiRHWGXVHXX09fxXDi-DqInchFD)
. I have a `controller`, which contains a function called register. All it does is route the `URL/URI` to the `view`. This `view` is also called register. In the `view` I display my basic `html` template, and a form in the content area. I currently use  procedural `PHP` within this view to collect the `POST` data given by the form and insert it into my `database`. So, throughout this paragraph you've heard no mention of any models, and from what I understand the model is what should be inserting the data into my `DB`.

1. Am I misusing or defeating the purpose of the `MVC` design pattern?
2. Is using procedural code in my `MVC` application appropriate?
3. If the answer to the first two questions are correct, how do I correct myself?
4. And, how do I collect the post data from my form with the model and give feedback to the view if certain conditions(e.g. username length) are inadequate.

Answer (score 1):

MVC is a software architectural pattern for implementing user interfaces.It divides a given software application into three interconnected parts, so as to separate internal representations of information from the ways that information is presented to or accepted from the user.

You can achieve MVC using object oriented, procedural, functional coding, just need to consider following things to make MVC,
The Controller controlls all processing, including determing what if anything was input, determing what model and view functions to call, and handling passing data to and from the model and view functions. 
The Model controlls all data access and manipulation, such as database io and any calculations. 
The View controlls all output formatting, such as creating an html page.

For making MVC in procedural coding context go to below link for detail:
http://www.fluffycat.com/PHP-Design-Patterns/Non-OO-MVC/

Comment: So how would i collect data from a user(e.g. with a form), and do it with OO-PHP?

Comment: First of all you need to setup View ( Form HTML), Controller to handle form post and model for handing insert queries. Once user will submit a form data will post on in Controller, then Controller will call model to process user data in DB. Go to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24712034/mvc-submit-form-to-controller-or-model  for an example of form post

Comment: So if I make the form, and a user is to click the submit button how will the controller know to get the data?

Comment: Actually , you need to make your controller accessible through a route. A controller action is assigned to this route in a bootstrap file like $framework->route('POST', '/userdata', 'UserdataController::action_form'); Then you need to pass controller's action route in form's action

Comment: I have the controller route users to the view so I'm not sure how to do what you're saying. my index.php is my bootstrap file. It starts a new instance of my app. My app's constructor takes the first / from the URL and what comes after that is the controller that the constructor looks for. After that it takes what is after the second / in the URL, and takes that as the method which it is to load from the controller. In that method I load the view(using the controller). So my controller is my routing system.

Comment: So in this case, you need to pass only your controller's method route where you are going to handle form submit. there you can get data with PHP's $_REQUESR['UserFrmDataVar']....

Comment: What are you saying? So, I should use the $_REQUEST in the controller method? It would be great if you could show me an example. Sorry if I sound like a noob, because I'm not. I'm just new to mvc.

Comment: Solved! I just put my logic in the controller. I was over-complicating it all.

Comment: But as per MVC ruled, Business logic should be in Model not in Controller.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to put the logic in the `controller`, because the `view` was required by php it didn't have to send the data.